# List of Edge Labels

Tags: labeling

1. Is there a way to retrieve a list of labels, either vertex or edge, from a graph?
2. Similarly, can a shape function access the label associated with the vertex or edge it is handed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access labels of a graph using "AbsoluteOptions". Here is an example:

We define same arbitrary graph:

```
vl = {1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c}; el = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2 -> e1, 
  2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> e2, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1 -> e3};
gr = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}, EdgeLabels -> el, VertexLabels -> vl]
```

[image]

To get the vertex labels:

```
VertexLabels /.  AbsoluteOptions[gr, VertexLabels]

{3 -> c, 2 -> b, 1 -> a}
```

Or if you only want the values.

```
{1, 2, 3} /. (VertexLabels /.  AbsoluteOptions[gr, VertexLabels])

{a, b, c}
```

and to get the edge labels:

```
EdgeLabels /.  AbsoluteOptions[gr, EdgeLabels]

{3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1 -> e3, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2 -> e1, 
 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> e2}
```

And the values:

```
{3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
  2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3} /.  (EdgeLabels /.  
   AbsoluteOptions[gr, EdgeLabels])

{e3, e1, e2}
```